# How do I get selenium driver using await and ESM with mocha?

Tags: node.js, selenium, ecmascript-6, mocha.js

I have code similar to this [gist](https://gist.github.com/jrgleason/6c23cdbc52e4e9eec2af4ba63d6ba115). Basically I am trying to use ESM with mocha so I have the hacky file with...

```
let driver = await import("./WireDriver.mjs");
```

The problem I am having is driver does not come back as either a promise or the actual driver. My breakpoints are not working thanks to an ancient version of chrome we use, but when I run...

```
console.log(`asdsa ${typeof d} ${Object.keys(d)} ${Object.getOwnPropertyNames(d)}`);
```

Comes back as

> asdsa object default default

How do I get the await to actually return the driver object?

**UPDATE**

I tried simplifying the WireDriver to...

```
const test = () => {
    return new Promise((res, rej) =>{
        res("This is a test");
    });
};

export {test}
```

Then tried to use it like this...

```
const base = await import("./WireDriver.mjs");
base.test().then((test)=>{
    console.log(`Is driver loaded? ${test}`);
});
```

And now when I run I get...

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: base.test.then is not a function

Answer (score 1):

This version seems to have worked...

```
import {BasePage} from "./pages/BasePage";

const driver = ()=>{
    let page = new BasePage();
    return page.driver;
};

export {driver}

(async () => {
   const base = await import("./WireDriver.mjs");
   const driver = await base.driver();
})
```